# How do I get nesting of css selectors in emacs?

Tags: css, emacs, nested

I'm using emacs 23.2.1 on ubuntu. 
The default css-mode was ancient and broken, so I removed it. In it's place, I started using css-mode-simple.el.

I use media queries, sass and scss, so I need to have nesting in my code. I don't write list, so I can't modify a css-mode myself to create proper indentation.

How can I get nested  selectors to indent properly in emacs?

Answer (score 1):

I use sass and scss as well and there is obvious solution for you - [sass-mode for Emacs](https://github.com/nex3/sass-mode). It's written by the Sass maintainer himself and it's great.